# Performance Testing First Steps

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, load

There's no problem, just a question; I'm starting formally do performance testing ( JMeter mostly ); and I've a concern.
How do the test work on real life? I mean, can I just "bombard" with some timing a specific endpoint? or is a "real-life" sequence of endpoints to simulate a "user flow"? or both cases apply for different stuff?
That'd really help; thanks a bunch and happy holidays everyone.

I've done solely the specific endpoint approach, but something tells me that that is not the right track.

PS
If somebody could recommend a good "Real-Life" approach tutorial, that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how do **you** implement the test.

Well-behaved load test must represent real life usage of the system under test by the real users (or upstream systems)

If you're talking about web applications performance testing first of all you need to ensure that [JMeter is configured to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) in terms of handling:

- embedded resources (scripts, styles, images, fonts, etc.)
- [cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching)
- [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)
- other [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)
- [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) requests
- think times
- etc.

And if your website assumes different groups of business users you should distribute the load accordingly using either different groups of requests or even different [thread groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) for this.